# Python function with for loop and if statement not working as well

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a column with numbers in a csv file and I want to compare them in a function but it won't works well, look below

```
  def newnumbers(list):
    for x in list:
        if x <= 0.4:
            return 1
        elif x <= 0.5:
            return 2   
        else:
            return 3

     thelist = pd.thecolumn
     pd['newnumbers'] = newnumbers(thelist)
```

here is what I get

```
    thecolumn newnumbers
 0  0.021     3
 1  0.003     3
 2  0.323     3
 3  0.576     3
 4  0.567     3
 5  0.687     3
```

but I want this

```
    thecolumn newnumbers
 0  0.021     1
 1  0.003     1
 2  0.323     1
 3  0.576     2
 4  0.567     2
 5  0.687     3
```

Comment: Do you use pandas?

Comment: Your function is returning *a single number*, based solely on the first value in the input list.  Your `for` loop never loops at all.  You need to accumulate the results in a new list, and return that outside of the loop.

Comment: is your indenting proper? please use other variable name than `list`, like `my_list`

Comment: Define a `newnumber` function that does the mapping for a *single* number rather than the entire list, and then call that function in a loop to build the `newnumbers` column.

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.select` and (maybe) change your condition `<= 0.5` by `< 0.6`:

```
import numpy as np

df['newnumbers'] = np.select([df['thecolumn'] <= 0.4,
                              df['thecolumn'] < 0.6],
                              choicelist=[1, 2], default=3)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   thecolumn  newnumbers
0      0.021           1
1      0.003           1
2      0.323           1
3      0.576           2
4      0.567           2
5      0.687           3
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem? or another answer?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using pandas, so use pandas/numpy methods:

```
import numpy as np
df['newnumbers'] = np.select([df['thecolumn'].le(0.4), df['thecolumn'].le(0.5)],
                             [1,2], 3)
```

output:

```
   thecolumn  newnumbers
0      0.021           1
1      0.003           1
2      0.323           1
3      0.576           3
4      0.567           3
5      0.687           3
```

*NB. you condition on the value ≤ 0.5 should have no match, maybe you mean ≤ 0.6?*

Comment: Not `<= 0.6` but `< 0.6`?

Comment: I don't know, could also be 0.568 for all we know, OP should clarify that ;) I just translated the original function

Comment: @sj95126 that's what I addressed in my answer. There is a flaw in the logic or in the output of the question.